# how to transfer native SOL from program to user

Tags: anchor, program

I have SOL in my program account. Is it possible to transfer that native (NOT WSOL) SOL to user?

If yes, How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this with an account that the program owns. The syntax used to access accounts is slightly anchor specific but the idea works in for regular solana programs too.

```
    let authority_lamports = ctx.accounts.authority.lamports();
    **ctx.accounts.authority.lamports.borrow_mut() = authority_lamports
        .checked_add(ctx.accounts.your_program_account.lamports())
        .unwrap();

    **ctx.accounts.your_program_account.lamports.borrow_mut() = 0;
```

Comment: authority is just the user's system program account. Usually `authority` is used to denote someone who has to sign a transaction to have control over some account.

Comment: Does solana panic/revert if your addition and subtractions dont match up? And if the account you are subtracting from isnt signing/the program?

Comment: Yes to both afaik

Answer (score 1):

```
    // creating SOL transfer instruction
    let ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
        from_pubkey, 
        &to_pubkey, 
        amount
    );

    // invoking SOL transfer instruction
    anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke(
        &ix,
        &[
            // from
            ctx.accounts.from_account.to_account_info(),
            // to
            ctx.accounts.to_account.to_account_info(),
        ]
    )?;
```

I think this should work for programs aswell. Ofcourse this would fail if amount is higher than balance or the "from" pubkey is not the signer

Comment: Pretty sure this only works when transfering Sol from accounts owned by the system program.

Comment: To clarify @henry-e's comment, this works if the program has a PDA that is a system account